# From XML inside CLOB, to Oracle table with list of paths

Tags: xml, oracle, path

The Oracle Version I am using is:

```
BANNER
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Productio
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

In a previous question, I've asked how to transform a clob into a table, see this:

[From XML to list of paths in Oracle PL/SQL environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146788/from-xml-to-list-of-paths-in-oracle-pl-sql-environment)

The answer I received was great, and it works for XML not too big.

But if I have a table called MY_TABLE_ONE with a field called MY_FIELD which is a CLOB with a very large content (for example 500 Kbytes), the following statement WON'T exit in a reasonable time:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_TWO
AS
   WITH PARAMS AS (SELECT   XMLTYPE (MY_FIELD) FROM MY_TABLE_ONE)
   SELECT   ELEMENT_PATH, ELEMENT_TEXT
     FROM   XMLTABLE (
               '              
      for $i in $doc/descendant-or-self::*
        return <element>
                 <element_path> {$i/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')} </element_path>
                 <element_content> {$i/text()}</element_content>
               </element>  
    '
                  PASSING (SELECT   * FROM PARAMS) AS "doc"
                  COLUMNS ELEMENT_PATH VARCHAR2 (4000) PATH '//element_path',
                          ELEMENT_TEXT VARCHAR2 (4000) PATH '//element_content'
            );
```

Is there any alternative way to transform an XML stored inside CLOB column, in an Oracle table with the list of the paths and the respective values, in a more EFFICIENT way?

The above statement is right, but it needs too much time to finalize.

Thank you very much for considering my request.

EDIT:

I've tried with this iterative solution, with NO SUCCESS :-(

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      CURSOR S_CUR
      IS
         WITH PARAMS AS (SELECT   XMLTYPE (MY_FIELD) FROM MY_TABLE_ONE)
         SELECT   ELEMENT_PATH, ELEMENT_TEXT
           FROM   XMLTABLE (
                     '              
      for $i in $doc/descendant-or-self::*
        return <element>
                 <element_path> {$i/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')} </element_path>
                 <element_content> {$i/text()}</element_content>
               </element>  
    '
                        PASSING (SELECT   * FROM PARAMS where rownum < 101) AS "doc"
                        COLUMNS ELEMENT_PATH VARCHAR2 (4000) PATH '//element_path',
                                ELEMENT_TEXT VARCHAR2 (4000) PATH '//element_content'
                  );

      TYPE FETCH_ARRAY IS TABLE OF S_CUR%ROWTYPE;

      S_ARRAY   FETCH_ARRAY;
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT=256';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE GOOFY99 DROP STORAGE';

      OPEN S_CUR;

      LOOP
         FETCH S_CUR
         BULK COLLECT INTO   S_ARRAY
         LIMIT 500;

         FORALL I IN 1 .. S_ARRAY.COUNT
            INSERT                                                  /*+APPEND */
                  INTO GOOFY99
            VALUES   S_ARRAY (I);

         COMMIT;
         EXIT WHEN S_CUR%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE S_CUR;

      COMMIT;
   END;
END;
```

Comment: Could you, please, post somewhere the problematically large XML file? (I hate to say it, but I don't know XmlQuery syntax yet, so I can't reverse engineer your XML structure from your select.)

Comment: The XML contains reserved data and tags, so I have to modify it before posting on the internet...  It's not so immediate!

Comment: Understood. No hurry.

Comment: I tried it on 12.1.0.2 EE against XML data constructed as `xmltype(cursor(select * from dba_objects))` (total of 46 MB of XML data stored in out-of-line CLOB). Your first query `CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_TWO AS ...` ran in 11.5 seconds. I'll try the same on 11.2 XE.

Comment: 11.2 XE, the same XML construction (total of 6.5 MB of XML data), the create table running in 90 seconds. Getting closer to your issue, I guess.

Comment: I believe that the problem is in the XQuery engine. 11g does it just slowly, 10g presumably as well. Bulk DML (`forall`) won't be of any use here, the trouble is deep inside the `select`.

Comment: What will you say about using `dbms_xmldom` package? Will it be appropriate decision?

Comment: Could somebody please post a solution for Oracle 10G with more performance?  I've offered a bounty for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD** I found quite big xml file (140 KB). My sistem: notebook with core i5 processor (2400 MHz), oracle 12c inside a virtual machine, time to process - 0.38 seconds. 
This method is the only alternative that I know. Example of xml here I found at w3schools.com.

```
declare
  xml_str clob := q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
 </CD>
</CATALOG>]';

v_doc  dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
node   dbms_xmldom.domnode;
txt    varchar2(4000);
type   t_list is table of number index by varchar2(4000);
v_list t_list;
  procedure enum_nodes(n dbms_xmldom.domnode, tag_name varchar2) is
    chn  dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    nl   dbms_xmldom.domnodelist;
  begin
    nl := dbms_xmldom.getchildnodes(n);
    for i in 0..dbms_xmldom.getlength(nl) loop
      chn := dbms_xmldom.item(nl, i);

      if dbms_xmldom.getnodetype(chn) = 1 then
         enum_nodes(chn, tag_name || dbms_xmldom.getnodeName(chn) || '/');
      elsif dbms_xmldom.getnodetype(chn) = 3 then
         v_list(tag_name || dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue(chn)) := 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
  end;
begin
  v_doc := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(xml_str);
  node := dbms_xmldom.makenode(v_doc);

  enum_nodes(node, '/');

  txt := v_list.first;
  while txt is not null loop
     dbms_output.put_line(txt);
     txt := v_list.next(txt);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: The output is: /CATALOG/CD/ARTIST/text()
/CATALOG/CD/COMPANY/text()
/CATALOG/CD/COUNTRY/text()
/CATALOG/CD/PRICE/text()
/CATALOG/CD/TITLE/text()
/CATALOG/CD/YEAR/text()    Why???

Comment: Sorry, as I understood, you need output like in your example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146788/from-xml-to-list-of-paths-in-oracle-pl-sql-environment. I just took another xml file. What output you need?

Comment: Instead of text() I need the value at every level.

Comment: Is there any way to show the path and the value into two separate fields?  Now I am running with my 500Kbytes XML to test the code...

Comment: @UltraCommit Thank you! :) Path - in variable `tag_name` of procedure `enum_nodes`, value - is a result of `dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue(chn)`. It is possible to accumulate them separately, but you need to make some changes. Here I use index table (variable `v_list` of type `t_list`) and its property to have only unique indexes. It can be only one index there, so you need to use another structure to accumulate values and then select unique.

Comment: I think that the best solution is to extract the substring at the right of the rightest slash ;-)