# oracle xmltable performace - converting clob to xmltype and extracting for multiple records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob, xmltype, xmltable

I have a specific issue. i am trying to retrieve values from a xml clob field in a column. this xml is very large and i have of over 40 thousand records that have this xml_clob. I am currently able to retrieve information using the displayed query but found that performance is a big issue. Currently, its take hours to process the query. i need to be able to reduce this query processing time just a few minutes. There is not xml_schema provided. Access to the server is very limited so i can can create is temporary Table. But this has not been much help. These follow query only displays "Gender". It takes minimum of 15 minutes.

example of xml

```
<root>
<entry>....</entry>
<entry effective="2010012108354553" timestamp="2010012108354553" id="12345">
  <field name="Org" t="0" s="4" d="0">
    <nv>0000</nv>
  </field>
  <field name="FirstName" t="1" s="13" d="0">
    <nv>John</nv>
  </field>
  <field name="LastName" t="1" s="13" d="0">
    <nv>Doe</nv>
  </field>
<entry>
</root>
```

query:

```
SELECT X.*,X2.*

        From XML_TABLE XM,
        XMLTABLE (
           'for $e in /entry
                 where $e/@type = "create"
                 and $e/@effective > 20110229
                 and $e/@effective < 20140229
                 return $e'
        passing extract(xml, '/root/entry') 
                  COLUMNS 
                  effective VARCHAR(60)  PATH  '/entry/@effective'
                ) AS X ,
        XMLTABLE (

        'for $i in /field
                 where $i/@name = "Gender"
                 return $i'


        passing X.xml 
                  COLUMNS 
                  name VARCHAR(60)  PATH  '/field/@name',
                  old_value VARCHAR(60)  PATH  '/field/ov',
                  new_value VARCHAR(60)  PATH  '/field/nv'
                ) AS X2
```

Comment: 40K rows is not much.  How large are these XML clob values?

Comment: Try another way like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753055/from-xml-inside-clob-to-oracle-table-with-list-of-paths/26845501#26845501

Comment: i checked the size of the clob field and does not pass .05 mb. Yet these clobs sizes will increase over time.

Comment: Thank you dmitry. But the solution provided will not work. i will need to use the xml information to map to existing tables in the oracle database. for example, i will need be able to map the id number to a person. I have attempted a similar solution the only difference is that the result were added to a temporary table. the result performance was much slower. My guess is that it has too many loops and and too many records. for example if 40 thousand persons and the xml have over 200 nodes then it will need to loop 8 million times.