# From XML to list of paths in Oracle 12c

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype, xmltable

[From XML to list of paths in Oracle PL/SQL environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146788/from-xml-to-list-of-paths-in-oracle-pl-sql-environment) shows how to list all the XPATHs of each XML element in an XML document and their corresponding values. My Question is how to list all the XPATHs of the XML elements **and** the XPATHs of their attributes and the corresponding values?

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_data ( xml ) AS
  SELECT XMLTYPE('
    <ALFA>
      <BETA>0123</BETA> 
      <GAMMA attribute1="value1">2345</GAMMA> 
      <DELTA attribute2="value2"> 
         <EPSILON attribute3="value3" attribute4="value4">3</EPSILON> 
      </DELTA> 
    </ALFA> 
  ')
  FROM DUAL;
```

**Expected Output**:

```
| ELEMENT_PATH                   | ELEMENT_TEXT |
|--------------------------------|--------------|
| ALFA                           | (null)       |
| ALFA/BETA                      | 0123         |
| ALFA/GAMMA                     | 2345         |
| ALFA/GAMMA/@attribute1         | value1       |
| ALFA/DELTA                     | (null)       |
| ALFA/DELTA/@attribute2         | value2       |
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON             | 3            |
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON/@attribute3 | value3       |
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON/@attribute4 | value4       |
```

Comment: Indicate what research you've done and what code you've tried.

Comment: i tried with attribute function, but it did not give me fullXPATH.

for $i in $doc/descendant-or-self::*
        return <element>
                 <element_path> {$i/string-join(attribute::*/name(.), ''/'')} </attribute_path>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/362b31/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_data ( xml ) AS
  SELECT XMLTYPE('
    <ALFA>
      <BETA>0123</BETA> 
      <GAMMA attribute1="value1">2345</GAMMA> 
      <DELTA attribute2="value2"> 
         <EPSILON attribute3="value3" attribute4="value4">3</EPSILON> 
      </DELTA> 
    </ALFA> 
  ')
  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select xpath, text
from   xml_data d
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTable( 
         'for $i in $doc/descendant-or-self::*
            let $path := $i/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')
            return <data>{attribute path {$path}, attribute value {$i/text()}}</data>' 
         PASSING d.xml AS "doc"
         COLUMNS xpath varchar2(4000) path '/data/@path', 
                 text  varchar2(4000) path '/data/@value'
       )
UNION ALL
select xpath, text
from   xml_data d
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTable( 
         'for $i in $doc/descendant-or-self::*
            let $path := $i/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')
            for $j in $i/attribute::*
              return <data>{attribute path { concat( $path, "/@", $j/name(.) ) }, attribute value {$j}}</data>' 
         PASSING d.xml AS "doc"
         COLUMNS xpath varchar2(4000) path '/data/@path', 
                 text  varchar2(4000) path '/data/@value'
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/362b31/1/0)**:

```
|                          XPATH |   TEXT |
|--------------------------------|--------|
|                           ALFA | (null) |
|                      ALFA/BETA |   0123 |
|                     ALFA/GAMMA |   2345 |
|                     ALFA/DELTA | (null) |
|             ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON |      3 |
|         ALFA/GAMMA/@attribute1 | value1 |
|         ALFA/DELTA/@attribute2 | value2 |
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON/@attribute3 | value3 |
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON/@attribute4 | value4 |
```

Comment: Thank you for response MTO,

Can i get ATTRIBUTE_NAME XPATH in ELEMENT_PATH along with other elements. i tried with attribute function but no luck.

Comment: |       ELEMENT_PATH | ELEMENT_TEXT | 
|--------------------|--------------|
|               ALFA |       (null) |
|          ALFA/BETA |         0123 |
|         ALFA/GAMMA |         2345 |
|         ALFA/GAMMA/attribute1 |         value1 |
|         ALFA/DELTA |       (null) |
|         ALFA/DELTA/attribute2 |         value2 | 
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON |            3 | 
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON /attribute3 |         value3 |
| ALFA/DELTA/EPSILON /attribute4 |         value4 |

Comment: @SrinivasAvoonuri Updated

Comment: Thank you MT0,  This answer my question and it made me to learn new techniques. Appreciate your help.