# Oracle query to extract XML Element values from a table dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, xmltype

I am looking for Oracle query which can be run on a table that has one of the column storing XML's
This query should dynamically take the xpath in the query to extract the string from all nodes. I have tried below but i have to hardcode the xpath. I do not want to hardcode the xpath.

Is there a way to generate the xpath, based on the structure of XML(structure may vary) on the fly to extract the xml node value?

Output i need is the extracted value of the xml node.

## I tried:

```
SELECT xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/fulcriteria/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/conumb/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/dup/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/reportdup[1]/dupsource/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/reportdup[2]/dupsource/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/reportdup[2]/dupnumb/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/reportdup[3]/dupsource/text()'),
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/reportdup[3]/dupnumb/text()') . 
       xmltype(XMLCOLUMN).EXTRACT('/report/final/dup/text()'),
  FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: "This query should dynamically take the xpath in the query to extract the string from all nodes" How are you providing this dynamic path? Is it in another table? Is it being passed in a bind variable? Something else? Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that includes all the details of how you are generating the query.

Comment: @MT0: Let me clarify, I have one table MYTABLE.XMLCOLUMN which store the XML Files. I am not storing xpath in any table. The XML follow some structure and has repeated blocks in it. As i know the structure so i am hardcoding the xpaths. Do i need a table to store the XPATH ?

Comment: You say that "query should dynamically take the xpath"; if it is dynamic then you need to pass the path from somewhere (tell us where and how). If it is not dynamic then you can use static paths (and I'm not sure what the point of this question would be). Whatever you chose you need to tell us what your specifications are as we can guess and make stuff up but its probably not going to be exactly what you intend. So why don't you work out exactly what you want and [edit] your question with a [MRE] that tells us what that is.

Comment: If you just want to list all paths and corresponding values in an XML document then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49039401/1509264

Comment: @MT0 : From that Post , i am getting error at line "PASSING d.xml AS "doc" saying "d.xml is invalid identifier" Not sure why as xml is the column of XMLTYPE.

Answer (score 2):

Join the table containing your dynamic paths with the table containing the XML and then use `XMLTABLE` to extract the value:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable ( id, xmlcolumn ) AS
SELECT 1, '<report>
  <fulcriteria>1</fulcriteria>
  <conumb>2</conumb>
  <dup>3</dup>
  <reportdup><dupsource>4.1</dupsource></reportdup>
  <reportdup><dupsource>4.2a</dupsource><dupnumb>4.2b</dupnumb></reportdup>
  <reportdup><dupsource>4.3a</dupsource><dupnumb>4.3b</dupnumb></reportdup>
  <final><dup>5</dup></final>
</report>' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE paths ( path ) AS
SELECT '/report/fulcriteria' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/conumb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/dup' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/reportdup[1]/dupsource' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/reportdup[2]/dupsource' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/reportdup[2]/dupnumb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/reportdup[3]/dupsource' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/reportdup[3]/dupnumb'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '/report/final/dup' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       p.path,
       x.value
FROM   MYTABLE t
       CROSS JOIN PATHS p
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         p.path
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.xmlcolumn )
         COLUMNS
           value VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '.'
       ) x
```

**Query 2**:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       p.path,
       XMLQUERY(
         (p.path || '/text()')
         PASSING XMLTYPE( t.xmlcolumn )
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS value
FROM   MYTABLE t
       CROSS JOIN PATHS p;
```

**Query 3**:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       p.path,
       XMLTYPE( t.xmlcolumn ).EXTRACT(p.path||'/text()').getStringVal() AS value
FROM   MYTABLE t
       CROSS JOIN PATHS p;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | PATH                           | VALUE
> -: | :----------------------------- | :----
>  1 | /report/fulcriteria            | 1    
>  1 | /report/conumb                 | 2    
>  1 | /report/dup                    | 3    
>  1 | /report/reportdup[1]/dupsource | 4.1  
>  1 | /report/reportdup[2]/dupsource | 4.2a 
>  1 | /report/reportdup[2]/dupnumb   | 4.2b 
>  1 | /report/reportdup[3]/dupsource | 4.3a 
>  1 | /report/reportdup[3]/dupnumb   | 4.3b 
>  1 | /report/final/dup              | 5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3cd55034cfc8687071355883c8b6375e)*

Comment: Alas, I couldn't make it work with a default namespace.
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6695a308ceede36952435f8b0c1d1689)*

Comment: @T-Gergely I couldn't immediately figure out the namespace issue with `XMLTABLE` but there are working versions using `XMLQUERY` and (the deprecated) `EXTRACT` functions in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1b54732ea7a6d1763941ee8ff4b1af1).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have a more complicated query, and only XMLTYPE.EXTRACT member function (that may not be deprecated) works and only with the NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE hint. XMLQUERY and the deprecated EXTRACT, EXTRACTVALUE all failed and not even consistently: no rows, null values, ORA-600 [qmxqrsWriteItemToOpn:itemTyp] and other errors. (12.1 Enterprise Edition with not too old patches.)